# Aliases in Synapse

Tags: synapse

Is there any way to add aliases / change items' priority in Synapse? For example, I want it to oper **F**ire**f**ox and not LibreO**ff**ice when I type `ff <return>`. Another example is that I want to open Final Term instead of plain Terminal or Terminator when I search for `term`, yet I still want both apps on my computer since Final Term is a bit shaky.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you might not be able to do this directly, but you can simply add *.desktop* file in the */usr/share/applications/* directory and use the alias as your name for the app. For instance, if you want to use **ff** for **Firefox**, add this file:

/usr/share/applications/ff.desktop

with this content:

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ff
Comment=FF shortcut to open Firefox
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Exec=/usr/bin/firefox
Terminal=false

This should do the trick. For details about *.desktop* files, you can read the [archlinux page about Desktop entries](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/desktop_entries).

Also note that you could simply copy the existing Firefox *.desktop* and adjust it:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop /usr/share/applications/ff.desktop
```

Then change the **Name** tag value to *ff*. Job done !